# "SELECT :parameter FROM .." in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to select a variable column name in my table, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT :day AS day FROM TABLE WHERE id= :id');               
$reponse->execute(array('day' => 'monday', 'id' => '5')); 
$day = $reponse->fetch();
```

Even by setting 'day', to a sure known element in my table (monday), it doesn't work. Same for id.

Does someone know how to fix that?

I have no php error output, only a mysql query error (that doesn't show).
By replacing ':day' by monday, I have an output.

Comment: You simply can't bind parameters like this.  Build the string with string concatenation, and be sure to validate the input to make sure it's a valid column or expression.

Comment: Concatenation is the only way? If it is, post as answer please

Comment: Where "valid input" means "use a [whitelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist)" in context.

Comment: What means Whitelist? Comparing variable to array of possibilities?

Comment: @user1824508 In this case, yes. But if the value *never* comes from the user (directly or indirectly) then such is largely a moot point.

Comment: It doesn't come from user. But I'd like to know more about this "Whitelist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the order in which the SQL is parsed, there's simply no way to use a bound parameter as part of the SQL statement (for example, a column or table name).

Instead, you'll need to build the string with string concatenation.  If the value of `:day` comes from an external source (database, POST parameter, etc), to avoid possible SQL injection attacks you'll want to validate the input to make sure it's a valid column or expression.

Answer (score 1):

Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO. You will need to filter and sanitize the data manually.